# UNremovable files/directory

Tags: linux, bash, rm

opensuse leap 15.4 on asus l210

I have unreadable/unremovable files on a usb fs. Could someone kindly explain the following sequence of commands, and what I might do to get rid of the problem?

```
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ ls -l
total 104
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 106496 Jul 21 13:33 i/
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ cd i
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik/i $ ls -l
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
total 0
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik/i $ cd ..
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ rm -r -f i
rm: cannot remove 'i': Directory not empty
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ sudo rm -r -f i
[sudo] password for root: 
rm: cannot remove 'i': Directory not empty
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ cd i
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik/i $ rm -f *
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik/i $ cd ..
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ rmdir i
rmdir: failed to remove 'i': Directory not empty
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ ls -l i/*.*
ls: cannot access 'i/*.*': No such file or directory
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ ls -l i
ls: reading directory 'i': Input/output error
total 0
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $
```

Whatever is on this fs was not created by chattr

```
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ sudo chattr -i i/*.*
[sudo] password for root: 
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat i/*.*
/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ sudo lsattr i/*
lsattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat i/*
```

If its any help, fdisk lists the device concerned as

```
Disk /dev/sda: 4.55 TiB, 5000947302400 bytes, 9767475200 sectors
Disk model: Elements 2621   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F7568B1B-3550-47AB-99FE-0C493E536C41
```

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 9767473151 9767471104  4.5T Microsoft basic data

As suggested by Kamil Maciorowski's comment below:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2021-09-14 r5237 [x86_64-linux-5.14.21-150400.24.33-default] (SUSE RPM)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Elements / My Passport (USB, AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD50NDZW-11BCSS0
Serial Number:    WD-WX72DB136EXY
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2bf8fe6d0
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    5,000,947,523,584 bytes [5.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    4800 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Dec  7 13:16:33 2022 PST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 1500) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  11) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30b5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4433
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       335
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       283
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       281
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       264
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       6499
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   120   105   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       241         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

 $ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                           
└─sda1 ntfs         Elements
                          F0220C5C220C29E4                        2.5T    45% /media/q/Elements

/media/q/Elements/bkp/Convert/Adams/Shardik $ rm -fr i|sudo dmesg|tail
rm: cannot remove 'i': Directory not empty
[   16.042041] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: stop vif 52:41:fc:92:46:60 on port 0
[   16.557898] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: start vif 20:4e:f6:78:42:fd on port 0
[   20.604282] wlan1: authenticate with d0:15:a6:0f:9a:d1
[   21.137016] wlan1: send auth to d0:15:a6:0f:9a:d1 (try 1/3)
[   21.137852] wlan1: authenticated
[   21.189079] wlan1: associate with d0:15:a6:0f:9a:d1 (try 1/3)
[   21.190102] wlan1: RX AssocResp from d0:15:a6:0f:9a:d1 (capab=0x1 status=0 aid=2)
[   21.190122] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: sta d0:15:a6:0f:9a:d1 joine  d with macid 0
[   21.190412] wlan1: associated
[   21.192561] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan1: link becomes ready
```

Comment: `Input/output error` means the filesystem is not healthy, possibly because of the drive not being healthy on the hardware level. `dmesg` just after the error may reveal something more. What is the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sda`? Is the filesystem NTFS? I believe there are no tools in Linux that can fully replace `chkdsk` for NTFS, so if the hardware turns out fine then you will probably need to use `chkdsk` in Windows to repair the filesystem.

Comment: Looks like chkdsk is required. lsblk shows fs is ntfs, dmesg shows nothing useful and smartctl -a /dev/sda says disk is healthy (I'm adding their outputs to the original post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the filesystem is ext2/3/4 or FAT you can use the fsck and badblock commands to fix the filesystem, then you should be able to delete them. If it's an NTFS file system it's really better to use chkdsk on Windows.
In either case if it's just a filesystem issue that should be enough but if any bad blocks are found you need to replace the drive immediately because more will definitely follow and you will lose data.